# how to share host's port to docker container, only one port, no network shearing

Tags: docker

I want to let a container(php/hhvm) to use host's SMTP server (postfix)

How do I do it?

Comment: port 25 already bing to some service in  host( not docker container)?

Comment: @yudongshen I updated question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: it is what i was looking for but there is no secure solution, seems like opening network with host makes all hosts ports open to docker which is bad - how to solve it?,  (not sure about following: )also bridge network makes docker's ports open to the world. there is no good solution.